# Combine the animation of the objects in one action

Tags: objects, actions

Can somebody help me? I've made these two spheres and need them to move in opposite directions through the orange tunnel. Each sphere is a single object. When I animated the objects using keyframes, I've obtained two actions, one for each object. I need the objects to move together and generate a single action. My intention is to upload the model to sketchfab, so the user may see the objects moving together. How can I achieve that?[image]

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible. Actions are object specific. However, what you can do is make them the same object and control them with one armature, or possibly use a constraint on one that mirrors the other.